# Select SQL Row value as columns like pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a table

```
 ID   TYPE  VALUE
1001   A       3
1002   A       4
1003   B       1
1002   B       5
1001   C       9
1002   A       4
1003   c       7
```

The output I need to get should look like this

```
 ID   TYPE A   TYPE B   TYPE C
1001   3         0        9
1002   8         5        0
1003   0         1        7
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Google:  "<your database name> pivot"

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Comment: You haven't even asked a question. You are supposed to come here with a concrete problem. Your only "problem", however, seems to be that you don't bother to look at the manual and write the query. We cannot help you with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try below `SQL` Query if don't want go `Dynamic` or `Pivot` :

```
SELECT id,
       ISNULL(SUM(CASE(type)
                      WHEN 'A'
                      THEN VALUE
                  END), 0) [TYPE A],
       isnull(SUM(CASE(type)
                      WHEN 'B'
                      THEN VALUE
                  END), 0) [TYPE B],
       isnull(SUM(CASE(type)
                      WHEN 'C'
                      THEN VALUE
                  END), 0) [TYPE C]
FROM <table_name>
GROUP BY id;
```

**Result :**

```
ID      TYPE A  TYPE B  TYPE C 
1001    3       0       9
1002    8       5       0
1003    0       1       7
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
   Select *

    From(
        'Insert Your Original Query Here or Table Name'    ) P

    Pivot   
        (Sum(Value)
            For TYPE in ([Type A],[Type B],[Type C]) As pvt
    Order By
        ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this dynamic sql

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max),
        @Columns nvarchar(max),@ColumnsType nvarchar(max)


SELECT @Columns=STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', '+QUOTENAME([TYPE])  FROM #table FOR XML PATH ('')),1,2,'')

SELECT @ColumnsType=STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', '+'ISNULL ('+QUOTENAME([TYPE])+','+'''0'''+') AS '+ 'Type'+[TYPE] FROM #table FOR XML PATH ('')),1,2,'')


SET @SQL='
SELECT ID,'+@ColumnsType+' From
(
SELECT * FROM #table
)
AS Src
    PIVOT
    (
    SUM(VALUE) FOR [TYPE] IN ('+@Columns+')
    )as Pvt
'
Print @SQL
EXEC (@SQL)
```

Result

```
ID      TypeA   TypeB   TypeC
-------------------------------
1001    3        0       9
1002    8        5       0
1003    0        1       7
```